# email from excel text on separate lines

Tags: excel, email

Got the macro to run and scrape names and mail addresses fine but i cannot get the text in the mial sent to appear on different lines , it appears as one long line of text. I tried adding vbline etc but it made no difference

in Sub mailtoo()

```
Dim OutApp As Object

Dim OutMail As Object

Dim cell As Range



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")



On Error GoTo cleanup

For Each cell In Columns("b").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _

       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "c").Value) = "yes" Then



        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail

            .To = cell.Value

            .Subject = "for Action"

            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _

                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

                    "line one of text here. " & _
                    "line two of text here" & _
                    "line three of text here" & _

                    "Regards" & _

                    "your name"





            .Attachments.Add "C:\demofilename.xlsx"

            .Send  'Or use Display

        End With

        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing

    End If

Next cell
```

cleanup:

```
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of that `VbNewLine` variable wherever you want a new line of text to appear:

```
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

                    "line one of text here. " & vbNewLine & _
                    "line two of text here" & vbNewLine & _
                    "line three of text here" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine &_

                    "Regards" & vbNewLine & _

                    "your name"
```

Just remember that the VB line continuation character `_` doesn't do anything special to strings, it's only intended to make your code itself more readable. If you remove the line continuations, which mean nothing to the runtime, your original code would just look like this in terms of what gets executed:

```
 "line one of text here. " & "line two of text here" & "line three of text here" & "Regards" & "your name"
```